# HTML frame - Prevent bootstrap popup to disappear when user click body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal popup to show a a message. When I am using the below statement inside a html frame then modal dialog is getting disappear when user click anywhere in the body . My requirement is to prevent this popup to disappear.

**$('#testModel').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="testModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body err-cnct">
                <h2><i class="demo-icon fa-lg icon-cancel"></i></h2>

                <p> <h4 class="modal-title">Connection Error!</h4>
                Connection to the Hub has been lost. <br/>Please check power and Ethernet connections. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show me live url so i can check what is the problem

Comment: From testing, I don't see the same issue. Check out this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jRPdxd39n9).

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options). Set a data attribute as such:

```
data-backdrop="static"
```